# What are the benefits of the different Jobs in Forsaken World?

Tags: forsaken-world

I'm just getting into the game (and I'm already hooked). I am leveling a Protector on my own, and a Human Assassin with my wife's Priest. My wife will be leveling a Marksman on her own.

Can anyone provide a summary of each Job and what they allow you to do in the game, and how they might be beneficial to the classes we are playing?

Comment: I'm too lazy to actually extract the important information from this thread, so I won't be posting it as an answer (someone else is welcome to use it do so). However, it seems to have the information you want: http://www.mmorpg-tactics.com/forum/english-section/180-forsaken-world-jobs.html#180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Botanist**

- This job will help you acquire the neccesary items for other jobs like Alchemy or Cooking.
- Collecting plants can help you make money

**Alchemy**

Alchemy will help you make potions that you can use to gain benefits:

- Basic Health Potion – Recovers 1640 HP
- Basic Mana Potion – Recovers 1370 MP
- Sturdy Potion – Increases defence by 15 for 5 minutes
- Valor Potion – Increases attack by 50 for 5 minutes
- Earth Mastery Potion – Increases Mastery by 30 for 5 minutes
- Light Mastery Potion- Increases Mastery by 30 for 5 minutes
- Water Mastery Potion- Increases Mastery by 30 for 5 minutes
- Wind Mastery Potion- Increases Mastery by 30 for 5 minutes
- Dark Mastery Potion- Increases Mastery by 30 for 5 minutes
- Physical Mastery Potion – Increase Physical Attack by 30 for 5 minutes.
- Basic Health Supplement – Increases Max HP by 200 for 10 minutes
- Basic Mana Supplement- Increases Max MP by 200 for 10 minutes
- Health Supplement- Increases Max HP by 400
- Mana Supplement- Increases Max MP by 400

**Mining**

- Minerals/Gems are used by Artisans
- Required for some quests

**Merchant**

- Unlocks new items in the Mercury Trade Union
- Gain reputation points

**Chef**

- Create food/drink
- Can boost Attack/Accuracy/Health/Recovery/etc.

**Artisans**

- Create jewelry

**Socialite**

- Special quests from Rio
- New skills:

  - Cooperative Efficiency: Cooperative Socialites can read the Book of Co-opto gain   EXP.
  - Exchange for Benefits: Exchanges Social Contribution for EXP or Gold Coins.
  - Persuade: Use this skill in front of an NPC. Complete quests using this skill to increase your Kindness
  - Intimidate: Use this skill in front of an NPC. Complete quests using this skill to increase your Cruelty.
- Some new daily quests

**Adventurer**

- Some new skills

  - Demon Hunt: Effective against monsters who have been affected by Darkness. Each use consumes a Hunting Gem.
  - Observe: Use this skill to trigger the Observe effect. Observing certain places can give you valuable information.

**Fishing**

- Allows you to catch fish (!)
- Chance of getting secret treasure
- Can open secret drift bottles
- Can gather coral

**Scavenger**

- Break down gear into materials used by weaponsmiths/armorsmiths
- Make recharger shards which increase max durability

**Tamer**

- Make money by selling pets

**Armorsmith**

- Create armor (!!)

**Weaponsmith**

- Create Weapons (!!)

*Extracted from [here](http://mmorpg-tactics.com/forum/english-section/180-forsaken-world-jobs.html#180)*